# How to unflatten an array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an array that I would like to unflatten in python? for example, I have this array

```
1 5 3
2 2 1
3 0 1
```

where the first column is the weight - which tells how many times to repeat the current row, so the final array should be

```
1 5 3
2 2 1
2 2 1
3 0 1
3 0 1
3 0 1
```

I have tried with numpy.tile (see code below) but numpy.tile gives a list of lists. My input file is different from the above example. One row in my array is

```
print(chain[5000])
```

which gives

```
 [6.000000e+00 5.425151e+02 2.164400e-02 1.184142e-01 1.041352e+00 6.197429e-02 3.062421e+00 9.833298e-01 5.551978e+00 1.488221e+00 1.784452e-01 6.769916e+00 3.820870e+00 2.267681e+01 1.730934e+00 3.170568e+00 8.731610e+00 1.072965e-01 1.683236e-02 6.379404e-02 3.155550e-01 8.292733e-02 1.427359e-01 3.369760e+00 9.844798e-01 9.684958e-01 6.746338e+01 6.908508e-01 3.091492e-01 1.407033e-01 6.451439e-04 9.492320e-02 8.225035e-01 4.573217e-01 6.133096e-01 1.001391e+00 2.418598e+00 8.601379e+00 2.137926e+00 1.888698e+00 1.189169e+03 5.628978e+03 2.563497e+03 8.283549e+02 2.338912e+02 9.833298e-01 2.450594e-01 2.463847e-01 2.733490e+00 1.385094e+01 1.090719e+03 1.454002e+02 1.041616e+00 1.395909e+01 1.058102e+03 1.483326e+02 1.389988e-01 1.619129e-01 3.346943e+03 1.021527e-02 8.216184e-01 4.542878e-01 7.185183e-02 9.269056e+01 1.391453e+03 6.754341e-01 4.776224e-01 6.124520e-01 1.066695e+03 1.833511e+01]
```

but
print(np.repeat(chain[5000], (int(chain[:,0][5000])), axis=0))
gives me an output of

```
[6.000000e+00 6.000000e+00 6.000000e+00 6.000000e+00 6.000000e+00 6.000000e+00 5.425151e+02 5.425151e+02 5.425151e+02 5.425151e+02 5.425151e+02 5.425151e+02 2.164400e-02 2.164400e-02 2.164400e-02 2.164400e-02 2.164400e-02 2.164400e-02 1.184142e-01 1.184142e-01 1.184142e-01 1.184142e-01 1.184142e-01 1.184142e-01 1.041352e+00 1.041352e+00 ... ]


ACT_chain = []
for i in range(len(chain[:,0])):
    chain_row = chain[i]
    ACT_chain.append(chain_row)
    if int(chain[:,0][i]) > 1:
        chain_row = np.tile(chain[i], (int(chain[:,0][i]), 1))
        ACT_chain.append(chain_row)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`numpy.repeat()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) for this:

```
import numpy as np

chain = np.array([
    [1, 5, 3],
    [2, 2, 1],
    [3, 0, 1]
])

np.repeat(chain, chain[:, 0], axis=0)
```

This gives you:

```
array([[1, 5, 3],
       [2, 2, 1],
       [2, 2, 1],
       [3, 0, 1],
       [3, 0, 1],
       [3, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: You beat me, I had the same ;)

Comment: Thanks @Mark. With np.repeat, I'm getting an array like 
    array([[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],[5, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0],[3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])

Comment: @user9404237 are you saying if you copy and paste the code above that's what you get? Or do you have some different input?

Comment: I have a different input, sorry. It's a huge file and it is chains from an MCMC run

Comment: It's hard to help if the question doesn't reflect your actual problem. The output you are getting looks like a transposed version of the output you want. For example, this produces that output: `np.repeat(chain.T, chain[:, 0], axis=1)` with this input.

Comment: @Mark, I edited the question to relect the actual problem